# Windows 10 error - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: vb.net

I am getting this error for SetPrinter method in winspool.drv while running my application in windows 10 machine. This issue found after upgrading to 4.6.1 .net frame work.

```
 Public Declare Function SetPrinter Lib "winspool.drv" Alias "SetPrinterA" _
    (ByVal hPrinter As IntPtr, _
     ByVal Level As Integer, _
     ByVal pPrinter As IntPtr, _
     ByVal Command As Integer) _
     As Long
```

But this works fine on Windows 7 machines.

Comment: That declaration alone is not raising that error. Please [edit] to include the code where you actually call the function.

Comment: The declaration is wrong, the return type is Boolean.  Lots of other ways to use it wrong, we can't see it being used.  Not otherwise limited to an ornery printer driver that isn't Win10 compatible.

Comment: you should consider ditching all of the interop-code altogether and create your own C++/CLR library which calls these functions natively - there is an automatic translation between Unicode and ANSI *(functionA <--> functionW)* for native code and its perfectly fine to use C++/CLR - libs within VB.NET, it works like a charm and can even be automatically compiled together with your VB app - its the *real* way to go, everything else is ... unstable and OS-version-dependent even though some parts of MSDN doc states otherwise .... not every microsoft employee is an expert for these things ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the support

I got this issue resolved by changing the target CPU as x86.